# What does oldstable,oldstable mean?

Tags: apt

Looking at available packages, I can see those that say `oldstable` and those that say `oldstable,oldstable`. What does the latter mean?

```
zsh-autosuggestions/oldstable 0.5.0-1 all
zsh-common/oldstable,oldstable 5.7.1-1+deb10u1 all
```

Comment: oldstable is a Debian term. It is not used in Ubuntu.

Comment: I thought they are one and the same because they use apt. Is this not the case?

Comment: @DilanEco `apt` and `dpkg` are just the packaging system.  Ubuntu and Debian are separate distributions with their own individual repositories.  `oldstable` is a Debian distro not an Ubuntu one, thus making it offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu.  Another analogy would be that just because Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, and other variants based on RHEL and the YUM package management system doesn't mean they're all the same distribution.

Comment: And yes while Ubuntu does *inherit* packaging from Debian, it's still a unique distribution with its own processes, repository servers, etc. which make it distinctly unique from Debian and the processes and procedures that Debian uses.

Comment: Ubuntu uses release codenames that aren't re-used; Debian uses references to what is current, thus it changes over time (what is *stable* becomes *oldstable*, then *oldoldstable* etc.. thus you need to know the date/time to understand what Debian provides, where as with Ubuntu's approach you do not; *xenial* was 16.04 when in development, released, even EOSS/ESM and doesn't change over time as Debian releases do.